# Hide specific category from wp_list_categories

Tags: categories, list

I have to hide 3 categories from the list, at the moment to view the list I use this function

```
function genres() {
$args = array('hide_empty' => true, 'title_li'=> __( '' ), 'show_count'=> 0, 'echo' => 0 );             
$links = wp_list_categories($args);
$links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a>', $links);
$links = str_replace(')', '', $links);
echo $links; 
}



<?php genres(); ?>
```

i need to hide category id 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`exclude` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#parameters):

> **'exclude'**
> *(array|string)* Array or comma/space-separated string of term IDs to exclude. If `$hierarchical` is true, descendants of `$exclude` terms
> will also be excluded; see `$exclude_tree`. See
> [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).

So with your `$args`:

```php
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'title_li'   => '',
    'show_count' => 0,
    'echo'       => 0,
    // Excludes specific categories by ID.
    'exclude'    => array( 1, 2 ),
);
```

Comment: where i can paste this code inside my code? thank you in advance!

Comment: I solved it, thank you very much !!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but just replace the whole `$args = array( ... )`; in your `genres()` function. Or you could just add `, 'exclude' => array( 1, 2 )` to your existing `$args`/array.